# Confusion in $ while using jquery and bootstrap together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and jQuery for same page. Previously i was using bootstrap typeahead for auto-completion but later decided to use jQuery autocomplete. But i am having problem with receiving the data autoselected. May be Its due to the confusion in the "$" sign as both jQuery and  Bootstrap use same sign correct me if i am wrong. My code is

```
            $('#startstop').autocomplete({ 
               source: stopNames,
                delay: 200,
                minLength: 2,
                onSelect:function (suggestion){
                    start = suggestion.value; 
                    console.log(start);       
                }
            });
```

the console shows object has no autocomplete method.

Comment: Does jquery ui exists on the page ???

Comment: It's not because of the `$` sign. Bootstrap uses jQuery, so it's the same thing.

Comment: To Bootstrap work needed Jquery! How may be conflict between them?

Comment: $ sign is of jquery, bootstrap use jquery so it use $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

include jquery Ui

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#startstop').autocomplete({ 
           source: stopNames,
            delay: 200,
            minLength: 2,
            select:function ( event, ui){
                start = this.value; 
                console.log(start);       
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked that way the autocompletion is added from the stopNames but the onSelect function is not invoked.Can u help me with that too.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a bootstrap problem first include `jquery` and then `jquery-ui`

Answer (score -1):

If  `$` sign is the problem then use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) ,you can change the **$** sign of`jQuery`.

**JS**:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
    (function( $ ) {
      $(function() {
        // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
      });
    })(jQuery);
```